# How to mock a bean in a test written in Micronaut Kotest

Tags: micronaut, mockk, micronaut-data, kotest

I am trying to add tests to test Controller, but mock the dependencies.

```kotlin
@MicronautTest
class PostControllerTest(private val posts: PostRepository, @Client("/") private val client: HttpClient) : StringSpec({

    "test get posts endpoint" {
        every { posts.findAll() }
            .returns(
                listOf(
                    Post(
                        id = UUID.randomUUID(),
                        title = "test title",
                        content = "test content",
                        status = Status.DRAFT,
                        createdAt = LocalDateTime.now()
                    )
                )
            )
        val request = HttpRequest.GET<Any>("/posts")
        val bodyType = Argument.listOf(Post::class.java).type
        val response = client.toBlocking().exchange(request, bodyType)

        response.status shouldBe HttpStatus.OK
        response.body()!![0].title shouldBe "test title"

        verify(exactly = 1) { posts.findAll() }
    }

    @MockBean(PostRepository::class)
    fun posts() = mockk<PostRepository>()
})
```

This does not work, due to the mocked `PostRepsoitory` can not be recognized.

Changed to the following when running tests.

```kotlin
@MicronautTest
class PostControllerTest(
    private val postsBean: PostRepository,
    @Client("/") private var client: HttpClient
) : FunSpec({

    test("test get posts endpoint") {
        val posts = getMock(postsBean)
        every { posts.findAll() }
            .returns(
                listOf(
                    Post(
                        id = UUID.randomUUID(),
                        title = "test title",
                        content = "test content",
                        status = Status.DRAFT,
                        createdAt = LocalDateTime.now()
                    )
                )
            )
        val request = HttpRequest.GET<Any>("/posts")
        val bodyType = Argument.listOf(Post::class.java).type
        val response = client.toBlocking().exchange(request, bodyType)

        response.status shouldBe HttpStatus.OK
        response.body()!![0].title shouldBe "test title"

        verify(exactly = 1) { posts.findAll() }
    }
}) {
    @MockBean(PostRepository::class)
    fun posts() = mockk<PostRepository>()
}
```

And got the exception like this.

```sh
io.micronaut.context.exceptions.BeanInstantiationException: Error instantiating bean of type  [com.example.PostControllerTest]

Message: Retrieving the port from the server before it has started is not supported when binding to a random port
Path Taken: new DataInitializer(PostRepository posts) --> new DataInitializer([PostRepository posts]) --> new PostControllerTest(PostRepository postsBean,[HttpClient client])
```

The `DataInitializer` is used to listen `StartupEvent` and insert sample data. How to make sure the application is started successfully before running the tests.

The complete code is [here](https://github.com/hantsy/micronaut-sandbox/tree/master/jdbc-kotlin).

There is [another mock example written in Junit5 and Mockito](https://github.com/hantsy/micronaut-sandbox/blob/master/post-service/src/test/java/com/example/PostControllerTest.java), it works well.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I found there are two approaches to overcome this barrier.

The first is using `Environment` to excludes `DataInitiliazer` bean.

```kotlin
@Requires(notEnv=["mock"])
class DataInitiliazer...
```

And run test with a `mock` env.

```kotlin
@MicronautTest(environments = ["mock"])
class PostControllerTest(
    private val postsBean: PostRepository,
    @Client("/") private var client: HttpClient
) : FunSpec({


    test("test get posts endpoint") {
        val posts = getMock(postsBean)
        every { posts.findAll() }
            .returns(
                listOf(
                    Post(
                        id = UUID.randomUUID(),
                        title = "test title",
                        content = "test content",
                        status = Status.DRAFT,
                        createdAt = LocalDateTime.now()
                    )
                )
            )
        val response = client.toBlocking().exchange("/posts", Array<Post>::class.java)

        response.status shouldBe HttpStatus.OK
        response.body()!![0].title shouldBe "test title"

        verify(exactly = 1) { posts.findAll() }
    }
}) {
    @MockBean(PostRepository::class)
    fun posts() = mockk<PostRepository>()
}
```

The second approach is mocking methods in the mocked `PostRepository` that will be called in `DataInitializer` bean. At the same time, inject an `EmbeddedServer` and create the `HttpClient` bean to make sure the port is available.

```kotlin
@MicronautTest()
class PostControllerTest(
   private val server: EmbeddedServer,
) : FunSpec({

    test("test the server is running") {
        assert(server.isRunning)
    }

    test("test get posts endpoint") {
        val postsBean = server.applicationContext.getBean(PostRepository::class.java)
        val client = server.applicationContext.createBean(HttpClient::class.java, server.url)
        val posts = getMock(postsBean)
        every { posts.findAll() }
            .returns(
                listOf(
                    Post(
                        id = UUID.randomUUID(),
                        title = "test title",
                        content = "test content",
                        status = Status.DRAFT,
                        createdAt = LocalDateTime.now()
                    )
                )
            )
        val response = client.toBlocking().exchange("/posts", Array<Post>::class.java)

        response.status shouldBe HttpStatus.OK
        response.body()!![0].title shouldBe "test title"

        verify(exactly = 1) { posts.findAll() }
    }
}) {
    @MockBean(PostRepository::class)
    fun posts(): PostRepository {
        val mock = mockk<PostRepository>()
        justRun { mock.deleteAll() }
        every { mock.saveAll(any<List<Post>>()) } returns listOf<Post>()
        return mock;
    }
}
```